# How do I parse strings in Java?

Tags: java

I have a few, theoretical ideas, but I don't know the language well.

I need to read in a line from the console, then see if parts match up with a symbol table, which includes the keywords: `"print [variable]"`, `"load [variable]"`, `"mem [variable]"`, `"sqrt"` and `"stop"`, as well as mathematical symbols.

It also needs to recognise the variables on their own (such as `"c = a + b"` as well.)

So...it's not that hard, in theory. You'd check the first character of the string matched up with keywords or variables. If they do, keep looping through that keyword or variable to check if it's the same string, up until you hit a space.

However, I don't know how to do that.

EDIT: To make it not "too broad", here's a rewording of the question: How do I check the characters of a read in string to compare to stuff in Java? Because the question wasn't obvious? I dunno.

Comment: OK. I asked specifically how do I check the characters of a read in string to compare to stuff. How the hell is that "too broad"? Is it that I had context for the question?

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is actually the very building blocks of a compiler and the very first part of it. What you are specifically referencing to in theory is basically a lexical analyzer. Tons of codes are available online for building compiler with all its building blocks. I suggest you read the theory on Compiler Construction, specifically the lexical analyzer part. Here are some links to it.
1.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis
2.https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compiler_Construction/Lexical_analysis
3.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_lexical_analysis.htm

I hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate it. However, the question was for the implementation in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i really understood your question . 
However, if you want to read user inputs from the console and store them into variables you can use the Scanner class , then you can use an If statement to check if the inputs contains the words you want and then handle them as you want .

Here is an example :

```
public class ReadConsole2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String toCheck = "what";

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Enter something : ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            if (toCheck.equals(input)) {
                // do something
               break;
            }

            System.out.println("input : " + input);
            System.out.println("-----------\n");
        }

        scanner.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that quite works if you've got say the toCheck is "what" but the line doesn't end at "what", and rather "what + what"